# can someone explain this line of Batch Script in detail

Tags: batch-file

```
forfiles /p "file location " /s /c "cmd/c IF @isdir==TRUE rmdir /S @path /Q" -D -30
```

I'm not understanding all the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explanation can be found, using `forfiles /?`, it's quite straightforward.
However one thing I can understand: the name of the command is `forfiles` but it also works for directories: the variable `@isdir` is used indeed in order to check if you're dealing with a file or a directory. Obviously, `@path` contains the entire path of the directory.